# How can we restore a deleted Category?

Tags: magento-1.7, category, category-products

I have a magento 1.7.0.2 store and accidently deleted a Category. I have an old backup of the Db but I can not restore it fully as I will loose recent orders and products. Is there any way to restore a category without restoring the whole DB. please help. thanks

Comment: Do you have any programming skills or are you looking to do this just from the the admin or other tools?   My first thought would be load the db backup into a *different* database and then you can access the data from there and either manually move it across or write a script to read from one DB and add to the other DB. Making sure that you back up the new DB first.

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal way to restore part of a Magento database.

If the backup version is the same as your production db you could experiment with dumping individual Magento category tables (with great caution :) ) and then importing them again, however as you say the backup is quite old you may then lose newer categories.

Even with a script to dump out the category data from a shop running the backup db rebuilding that category automatically can be problematic, e.g. category ID's may change.

Unfortunately in a scenario like this there is no quick fix, and my experience shows that even when you manage to export/import the data you still need to manually edit categories and products to restore it fully.

I think your best bet is to load the old database into a dev server, login to admin on the old database shop and log into admin on the production shop. Load the admin category screens side by side, and then add the category data manually using copy and paste for text, descriptions etc.

You would then need to import product data or manually add the products to the new category.